# JS- how to remove duplicate JSON nodes and add one link for all nodes that get merged

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js, graph, visualization

`enter code here` I have a JSON File from which I want to create a d3 directed 
 graph with arrows in the direction of higher influence score

```
{"nodes":[{"Name":"GJA","influenceScore":81.0,"type":10.0},
{"Name":"JJZ","influenceScore":82.6,"type":30.0},
{"Name":"SAG","influenceScore":89.0,"type":30.0},
{"Name":"JJZ","influenceScore":82.6,"type":30.0}],"links":
[{"source":0,"target":0,"type":"SA","value":1},
{"source":0,"target":1,"type":"SA","value":1},
{"source":0,"target":2,"type":"SA","value":1},
{"source":0,"target":3,"type":"SA","value":1}]}
```

I am a d3novice, so would like some help from experts here
My d3 code is here:

```
.link {
 stroke: #ccc;
 }

.node text {
 pointer-events: none;
 font: 12px sans-serif;
 }

</style>


<body>
<script src="//d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
<script>
var width = 1200,
    height = 900;

var color = d3.scale.category10();
var fill = d3.scale.category10();
var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
   .attr("width", width)
   .attr("height", height);

var force = d3.layout.force()
   .gravity(0.052)
   .distance(350)
   .charge(-20)
   .size([width, height]);

d3.json("\\abc.json", function(error, json) {
 if (error) throw error;

 force
  .nodes(json.nodes)
  .links(json.links)
  .start();

var link = svg.selectAll(".link")
   .data(json.links)
   .enter().append("line")
   .attr("class", "link").style("stroke-width", function(d) { return 
    Math.sqrt(d.value); }).style("stroke", function(d) {return 
    fill(d.value);});

var node = svg.selectAll(".node")
  .data(json.nodes)
 .enter().append("g")
  .attr("class", "node")
  .call(force.drag);

  node.append("circle")
  .attr("class", "node")
  .attr("r", function(d) { return (d.influenceScore/10) + 10; 
  }).style("fill", function(d) { return color(d.type); });

  node.append("text")
  .attr("dx", -35)
  .attr("dy", "4.5em").text(function(d) { return d.Name });


  node.append("title").text(function(d) { return d.Name ;});


 force.on("tick", function() {
  link.attr("x1", function(d) { return d.source.x; })
    .attr("y1", function(d) { return d.source.y; })
    .attr("x2", function(d) { return d.target.x; })
    .attr("y2", function(d) { return d.target.y; });

node.attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + 
 ")"; });
   });
  });
```

I am getting the following image [image]

I would like the target node  e.g JJZ here just to occur once ( currently it's occurring as many number of times as it is repeated  in the JSON i.e 2 times in the given example)  however the line joining the two nodes should increase in thickness depending on the number of times the nodes repeat. so the blue line linking JJZ with GJA should be thicker than GJA and SAG and if another node occurs 5 times that should be thicker than JJZ and GJA. Also how do I insert directed arrows in the direction of a higher influence score

Answer (score 1):

Your question here has little to do with D3: you can manipulate your array with plain JavaScript.

This function looks for the objects on `json.nodes` based on the property `Name`. If it doesn't exist, it pushes the object into an array that I named `filtered`. If it already exists, it increases the value of `count` in that object:

```
var filtered = []

json.nodes.forEach(function(d) {
  if (!this[d.Name]) {
    d.count = 0;
    this[d.Name] = d;
    filtered.push(this[d.Name])
  }
  this[d.Name].count += 1
}, Object.create(null))
```

Here is the demo:

```js
var json = {"nodes":[{"Name":"GJA","influenceScore":81.0,"type":10.0},
{"Name":"JJZ","influenceScore":82.6,"type":30.0},
{"Name":"SAG","influenceScore":89.0,"type":30.0},
{"Name":"JJZ","influenceScore":82.6,"type":30.0}],"links":
[{"source":0,"target":0,"type":"SA","value":1},
{"source":0,"target":1,"type":"SA","value":1},
{"source":0,"target":2,"type":"SA","value":1},
{"source":0,"target":3,"type":"SA","value":1}]};

var filtered = []

json.nodes.forEach(function(d){
 if(!this[d.Name]){
   d.count = 0;
   this[d.Name] = d;
    filtered.push(this[d.Name])
  }
  this[d.Name].count += 1
}, Object.create(null))

console.log(filtered)
```

Then, you just need to use the property `count` to set the `stroke-width` of your links.

Comment: @ Gerardo Furtado Thanks! for demonstrating how to merge the nodes and increase the count to reflect how many nodes were merged. However I am not sure how do we take care of the links with each node, because I can merge  nodes and increase count but how do I keep just one link depicting all nodes that have been merged

Comment: @Pearl You not only have to use that merged array for the nodes, you'll have to change the links array accordingly, since the source/target indices have changed. Here is a fiddle with hardcoded values in the links array, just to show you how it works: https://jsfiddle.net/eLe62puy/

Comment: .Thanku for such a gr8 solution!

Comment: you had helped me with this problem sometime ago , could you also elaborate on how to add arrows which point in the direction of  higher to a lower influence score?

Comment: Please, post this issue as a new question.

Comment: I created a separate stackoverflow question . here's the link : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46896285/js-d3-how-to-add-arrows-to-a-force-diagram